# Receiving extra bytes in socket transmission

Tags: python, android, sockets, networking, raspbian

So I wrote up a program that communicates via wifi direct between a raspi and an android phone using the python socket library. It’s super simple rn, currently the phone sends “Whats up!” And the pi receives it and prints what it receives. It works except it’s very unreliable and I am getting some wierd additional bytes in the message.

When sending “Whats up!” I receive either 
`b’\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\tWhats up!’` Or 
`b’\xac\xed\x00\x05’`

I’m assuming that the second outcome is due to a lost packet, but I’m not sure what all of the stuff at the beginning of the message is. When I change the message to “Whats up! Test 1!!” I get 
`b’\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x12Whats up! Test 1!!’` (notice that there is now an added `\x12`)

Can anyone explain to me what this is? Is it some part of the socket protocol? And how can I account for it in my program?

for reference, the program running on my pi looks like this:

```
import socket;


server = socket.socket();
host = "192.168.4.1";
port = 4444;

server.bind((host,port));

server.listen();

client, addr = server.accept();
print (str(client.recv(2056)));

client.close();
```

here is my android client code as well, in case it's relevant

```
    public void runClient() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        tcpSocketManager.addTextToScreen("Starting Client Socket " + groupOwnerAddress + " " + port);
        socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(groupOwnerAddress, port)), 1000);
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(new String("Whats up!"));

        oos.close();
        os.close();
        socket.close();
    }
```

Comment: You're using an ObjectOutputStream to write the string.  This writes the output in a format used by Java serialization.  What you're seeing at the beginning is Java saying "This is a java.lang.String of length 8".  You need to write directly to the OutputStream `os`.  Notice that the byte just before the string is \t, a tab, which is ascii 8.  You then change your string to length 18, and just before the string you get \x12.

Comment: ohhhhh okay that makes sense, thank you so much. If you put that into an answer I'll make it the accepted answer

Comment: Done.  And even improved it slightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `OutputStreamWriter` rather than an `ObjectOutputStream`.  The latter is for writing Java serialized objects.

It's been about two years since I've written Java, but I think this is correct.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
writer.write("What's up!");
```

Comment: Thanks! Can confirm that the ObjectOutputStream was the issue, and using an OutputStreamWriter, as well as writing to the OutputStream directly, was able to fix the problem